# Why does the order of input to this LCM finding program change the output?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class LCM {

    static int GCF(int first, int second){
        int FIR = first;
        int SEC = second;

        ArrayList<Integer> prime1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> prime2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int n = 1;

        // for the specific case of 2
        while(true){
            if(FIR % 2 == 0){
                FIR /= 2;
                prime1.add(2);
            }
            else break; 
        }
        // for the rest of the prime numbers
        for(int i = 3;;i = 2*n + 1){
            if(FIR < i) break;

            if(FIR == i) {
                prime1.add(i);
                break;
            }

            if(FIR % i == 0){
                FIR /= i;
                prime1.add(i);
            }

            ++n;
        }
        // initialize n back to 1
        n = 1;
        // for the specific case of 2
        while(true){
            if(SEC % 2 == 0){
                SEC /= 2;
                prime2.add(2);
            }
            else break;
        }
        // for the rest of the prime numbers
        for(int i = 3;; i = 2*n + 1){
            if(SEC < i) break;

            if(SEC == i){
                prime2.add(i);
                break;
            }

            if(SEC % i == 0){
                SEC /= i;
                prime2.add(i);
            }

            ++n;
        }
        // Collect all common prime factors to calculate GCF
        List<Integer> common = new ArrayList<Integer>(prime2);
        common.retainAll(prime1);
        int GCF = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < common.size(); i++){
            GCF *= common.get(i);
        }

        return GCF;
    }
    // End of LCP function

    static int lcp(int first, int second){

        return (first / GCF(first, second)) * second;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int first = 0;
        int second = 0;
        while(true){
            System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
            first = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
            second = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("LCM (" + first + ", " + second + ")" + " = ");
            System.out.print(lcp(first, second) + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly when I give it input in one order but it give's the wrong output when I reverse the order of input. For example it outputs

```
LCM(12, 10) = 56
```

when I input the two numbers in the order 12 then 10. But it outputs

```
LCM(10, 12) = 24
```

when the input is reversed. I tried debugging the code but I couldn't see any obvious problem.

Comment: Post your algorithm. I would suspect you need to swap your inputs before starting the calculation. Also not convinced that either `56` _or_ `24` are correct...

Comment: Well the output is incorrect in the first function call as well, so I guess your function is not correctly written

Comment: LCM of `12` and `10` is 60

Comment: How can `56` be the `LCM` of _anything_ and `10`?? Since when is 56 a multiple of `10`?

Comment: Thank's. But I still would like to know what's making my code not work. P.S. I meant to say 60 not 56. Really sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LCM` of `(10, 12)` is `60`, **NOT** `56`

If you wish to calculate the LCM of two numbers entered by the user, here's a simpler version that calculates the LCM

```
class LCM {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int first = 0;
        int second = 0;
        while(true){
            System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
            first = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
            second = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("LCM ("+first + ","+second+") = " +lcp(first, second) + "\n");
        }
    }

    public static int gcf(int first, int second) {

        HashSet<Integer> firstFactors = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<Integer> secondFactors = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<Integer> commonFactors;

        //factors of first number
        for(int i=1; i<=first; i++) {
            if(first%i == 0) {
                firstFactors.add(i);
            }
        }

        //factors of second number
        for(int i=1; i<=second; i++) {
            if(second%i == 0) {
                secondFactors.add(i);
            }
        }

        commonFactors = new HashSet<>(firstFactors);

        commonFactors.retainAll(secondFactors);

        return Collections.max(commonFactors);
    }

    static int lcp(int first, int second){

        return (first / gcf(first, second)) * second;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off using `Set` rather than `List`. Also, you probably want _prime_ factors...

Comment: You are right about using a `Set` in this case instead of a `List` but no need of prime factors in this case because LCM is being calculated using the GCF of two numbers